# SBT Plugin use classpath of compiled sources

Tags: sbt

I have an SBT Plugin and in this plugin I want to instantiate classes that were compiled as part of the compile step.

Essentially, think of my plugin as doing this:

`classOf[com.skamuel.Dummy].newInstance` where Dummy is a class compiled by the build.

But when I try this, I get class not found exception. I can execute the above code in the console after executing the compile task, just not as part of a plugin.

So, what classpath magic do I need to do to get the above to work?

Comment: Are the classes part of a build project or the project you're building?

Comment: The classes I want to reflectively instantiate are part of the project that includes the plugin. So if the plugin is X, then the classes are part of project A that uses plugin X.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your plugin can use runtime class path of the compiled project to which it is added, but it cannot use it at the compile time. This is logical I guess, your plugin exists without knowing of your project.

Given that you could use the mentioned class like this:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import classpath._

object MyPlugin extends Plugin {

  val createClass = taskKey[Unit]("Creates new instance of a class")

  lazy val myPluginSettings = inConfig(Compile)(Seq(
    createClass := {
      // we need to make sure the class we want to use is compiled
      val analysis = (compile in Compile).value
      // create custom class loader from the output of compile plus other deps
      val classpath = (fullClasspath in Compile).value.map(_.data)
      val loader = ClasspathUtilities.makeLoader(classpath, scalaInstance.value)
      val myClass = Class.forName("com.stackoverflow.lpiepiora.MyClass", true, loader).newInstance
      println(myClass.asInstanceOf[{def helloWorld(): String}].helloWorld())
    }
  ))

}
```

The problem is that you cannot do much with the class, as plugin cannot cast it directly to the type - it doesn't know it.

I'm using structural type for the example, as I have my class defined as

```
package com.stackoverflow.lpiepiora
class MyClass {
  def helloWorld(): String = "Hello World"
}
```

You can also check the complete, working example in [my GitHub repository](https://github.com/lpiepiora/stack-overflow/tree/master/solutions/q-23904666)

Comment: This looks like it will do what I want. I will test and come back to accept.

Comment: It seems to find my class now, but can't find scala/Product. So it seems we need to add the standard scala library to the loader as well?

Comment: @monkjack yes you're right, sorry- you can pass a parent class loader from the `scalaInstance`, I'll update my answer.

Comment: That's what the current call does, it passes the root loader, is there another loader that has the context of the build?

Comment: @monkjack I have updated again my answer to include [scalaInstance](http://harrah.github.io/xsbt/latest/sxr/Keys.scala.html#316205) classloader, which contains the scala classes.

Comment: You sir are a genius. You should be working with Eugene and Josh with this level of SBT knowledge.

Comment: Almost there :) How do I add in the rest of the dependencies for the build? Seems the scalaInstance is good for the scala lib, but not the rest of the deps. I will attempt to figure it out myself before you come back and impress me again.

Comment: I've updated your answer with the final working version.